# Backup postgresql WAL logs

Tags: postgresql, backup, recovery, wal

I try to configure backuping database in postgresql with  pg_basebackup and WAL logs.
For now I created full backup once a week and want to backup wal logs too. But, as I understand, posgresql writes them all the time. So, how can I copy them and be shure that they are not corrupted?
Thanks

Comment: It is explained in documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL

Answer (score 1):

You set `archive_command` to a shell command that copies the WAL file to a safe archive location, so that burden is mostly on you.

When PostgreSQL runs `archive_command`, it assumes that the WAL file is not corrupted. Only a PostgreSQL bug or a bug in the storage system could cause a corrupted WAL segment.

There is no better protection against PostgreSQL bugs than always running the latest bugfix release, and you can invest in storage hardware that will at least detect failure.

You can also write your `archive_command` with a certain amount of paranoia, e.g. by comparing the `md5sum` of the WAL segment and its archive copy.
Another idea is to write two copies of the WAL file to different storage systems.

Comment: It's the paranoia which make us alive. Despite the jokes, Depending your database size and database integrity ensurement you need, you could write some automation to restore the original database for testing purposes, if it works then your backup have integrity, if it don't then you can check which Wal file is corrupted and recover it from pg_wal dir (it looks like postgresql don't delete it immediately,  if I get it).

Comment: I think it would be great if postgresql write some tool just to check the  Wal files backup and could check if the Wal files set have integrity